# Write size with java.util.zip

Tags: java, zip, size

I noticed that creating a .zip file using the `java.util.zip` library doesn't write the size properly and because of that

```
zipEntry.getSize; //created with a ZipInputStream (zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry())
zipEntry.getCompressedSize();
```

both always return `-1`.

This doesn't happen if I create `zipEntry` with a `ZipFile` and `Enumeration` - which I can't do in this particular case.

How do I make the library write the sizes properly?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code and returned sizes were good.

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/foo.zip")));
ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();
System.out.println(entry.getSize());
System.out.println(entry.getCompressedSize());
zis.close();
```

I think the problem does not come from the way you call the library but might come from your zip file.

Comment: It's only a problem if the zip file was created by the library, if you zip everything with e.g. WinRar, it's fine. I've tested it with multiple files, half of them were created using the library, the other half I created with WinRar. If I unzip something that was zipped by the library, then zip the resulting files again with WinRar, it returns the proper size. Furthermore, I'm not using `File` because I'm working with "Storage Volume" (Android), which is also the reason why I can't use `ZipFile` (or `File` and `FileInputStream`) at all.